# Плагины для компонента HtmlEditor библиотеки ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

Здравствуйте!

Есть ли плагины для HtmlEditor ?

Нужно собственно не так уж и много:

- Редактировать ссылки после их создания (стандартный инструмент почему-то не может редактировать)
- Вставлять и управлять положением изображений
- Вставлять и редактировать таблицы
- Разделять текст на абзацы (то есть вставлять тэги не перевода строк, а абзацев)

И будет неплохо, если кто-нибудь даст ссылку на русскоязычную документацию ExtJS 4.1
Ну или хотя бы на русскоязычные статьи по теме...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще обратите внимание на [эту](http://www.point-constructor.com/en/tinyta/) библиотеку. Она позволяет интегрировать [TinyMCE](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyMCE) с Extjs.

Answer (score 1):

Несколько описано прямо тут [Sencha.com/forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?72106-Ext.ux.form.HtmlEditor.Plugins), на *английском*.
Ещё неплохая идея была на Хабре - [Плагин добавления изображений в текст](http://habrahabr.ru/post/110186/), - вполне *по-русски*.

Большую часть Ваших нужд эти плагины должны решить, если нет всегда можно написать свои, а приведенные использовать в качестве примеров при разработке...